# Best way to find sectionId by slug

Tags: plugin-development, sections

What would be the best way of finding a `sectionId` by its slug within my plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
$section = craft()->sections->getSectionByHandle('sectionHandle');
$sectionId = section->id;
```

Comment: what about categories? craft()->categories->getCategoryByHandle('handle'); is not working.